# Find sine in Java

Tags: java, math

Can anyone give me a quick tip?

For example....how would I find the sine of 90 degrees?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [Math.sin](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)) function where the argument is given in radians. Example:

```
double result = Math.sin(Math.PI / 2.0);
```

Comment: Thanks! so Math.sin(90) should do it.

Comment: No, it won't do it. The argument should be in radians. `Math.sin(Math.PI / 2)` should work.

Comment: No it's in radians... so 90 deg = PI/2 rad

Answer (score 19):

The sin function in java.lang.Math expects a parameter expressed in radians.

I think you should use Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90))

Answer (score 5):

A few tips for you:

- [Math#sin() function](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)), which takes angle in *radians*,
- radian = pi / 180 degrees

What if you combine these two tips?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90))
```

Comment: -1 as mentioned in other comments, the sin() method takes the angle in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

It has a `sin(double)` method among other mathematical functions. It takes the angle in radian, so you'd have to do the conversion from degree. For that purpose (and others), Math also has the `PI` constant.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`java.lang.Math`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class.